# excel : no vba : referance or link cell to a remote server data with variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula, remote-server, excel-indirect

I have a cell referanced to a remote server with formula:

```
=serv~10~0'!'23'*1
```

10 should be the variable referanced to a cell in the same sheet

I tried this but didn't work

```
=INDIRECT("serv~" & $A$1 & "~0'!'23'*1")
```

any idea how to do it!!

Comment: What are you trying to reference?? File or whatever? via network or.....?

Comment: it's an installed program server that takes data from source server via network connection... so the cell will referance a data from a data server installed on my machine. if I change 10 to 20 this will referance to another field on the installed data server, how can I referance this part of the formula as a variable.

Comment: I don't think such syntax is ever possible: using `INDIRECT` you may reference to Excel workbook only. Moreover, if you want to reference a cell into another workbook - this workbook MUST be opened, otherwise it will return `#REF!`.

Comment: so end of road with vba..thanks brother.

Comment: no problem, glad you found the solution! You may submit it as your own answer and accept in a few days.

Comment: I mean at the end we have to go with vba to achieve this. list box click event handler. it's a little bit slow even with putting screenupdate off.

Answer (score 0):

1 vba solution:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim cmpCd As String
cmpCd = CStr(Cells(1, 1).Value)

'field title = company name
Cells(2, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=serv~" & cmpCd & "~0'!'23'*1"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```